# hard to understand error in angularjs app "Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just added a block of code that works in other pages, but in this particular page I get this error, I am not sure why or how to read/understand what is wrong from this error message cause it doesn't seem to me that is pointing to anywhere in specific.

```
 index.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
        at coerceArray (index.js:24)
        at new AES (index.js:195)
        at new ModeOfOperationCBC (index.js:444)
        at _decrypt (bcs.cryptoStorage.js:51)
        at Object.getSessionData (bcs.cryptoStorage.js:91)
        at Object.isLogged (bcs.auth.js:30)
        at AppBootRun (app.boot.js:112)
        at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:18000)
        at ionic.bundle.js:17808
        at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:13696)
```

the block of code I added was

```
$scope.lang = localStorage.getItem("i18n-lang");
$scope.activateLangEN = function () {
    $scope.lang = "en-US";
    console.log("was called activateLangEn " + $scope.lang);
    localStorage.setItem("i18n-lang", $scope.lang);
    localStorage.setItem("targetLang", $scope.lang);
    location.reload();
}
```

I force the app to reload again to change it's language according to 
what is in the localstorage, on app config I use translateProvider.

Not sure what went wrong here. Anything I should consider in specific?

html:                     `<div class="langChange mt20"><span ng-click="activateLangPT()">PT</span> | <span ng-click="activateLangEN()">EN</span></div>`

Comment: What line of code is around/on index.js:24?

Comment: Method `coerceArray` tries to call `something.buffer` but `something` is `undefined` so it doesn't has property `buffer`. It's hard to say what is `something` and what is wrong with it based on info in OP. IMO this seems to fail during authentication after page reload. Does it work for other pages **in the same** application?

Comment: DominicOrim , is this if right here, I think this is from angular itself though, function coerceArray(arg, copy) {

        // ArrayBuffer view
        if (arg.buffer && ArrayBuffer.isView(arg) && arg.name === 'Uint8Array') {

            if (copy) {

Comment: @barbsan first of all, thank you, yes it is working at the login page before the login is confirmed, so maybe it does have to do with something that turns into undefined after login is concluded, I will have to very carefully debug this

Comment: Do you need to call `location.reload()`? `$translate.use($scope.lang);` doesn't work? [Source](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language#multi-language_source)

Comment: yes this works , thanks , you saved my day! @barbsan

Comment: @AnaSequeira that's great, but you may get the same issue after page refresh, so it's worth to look closer at it anyway